# Edit Bootstrap modal sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to apply Bootstrap slide up transition effect same as to slide down. I tried many ways to do it.

I tried to adding .fade to linear but end transition quickly gone away. Not like slide in transition.

```
.fade-custom {
  transition: all 0.80s linear !important ;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7zqk956/1/)

Any ways to fix this ?

Comment: Please don't link to jsfiddle, post your code here on stackoverflow. You can even create a fiddle here right in your post, that makes it easier for people to analyze and recreate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.modal.fade:not(.in) .modal-dialog {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade fade-custom" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close " data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it'd help.

Answer (score 1):

Using animate.css

```js
function testAnim(x) {
    $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog  ' + x + '  animated');
};
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var anim = $('#entrance').val();
      testAnim(anim);
})
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var anim = $('#exit').val();
      testAnim(anim);
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css'>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" style="position:absolute; top:40%; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Entrances</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="entrance">
        <optgroup label="Attention Seekers">
          <option value="bounce">bounce</option>
          <option value="flash">flash</option>
          <option value="pulse">pulse</option>
          <option value="rubberBand">rubberBand</option>
          <option value="shake">shake</option>
          <option value="swing">swing</option>
          <option value="tada">tada</option>
          <option value="wobble">wobble</option>
          <option value="jello">jello</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Bouncing Entrances">
          <option value="bounceIn" selected>bounceIn</option>
          <option value="bounceInDown">bounceInDown</option>
          <option value="bounceInLeft">bounceInLeft</option>
          <option value="bounceInRight">bounceInRight</option>
          <option value="bounceInUp">bounceInUp</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Fading Entrances">
          <option value="fadeIn">fadeIn</option>
          <option value="fadeInDown">fadeInDown</option>
          <option value="fadeInDownBig">fadeInDownBig</option>
          <option value="fadeInLeft">fadeInLeft</option>
          <option value="fadeInLeftBig">fadeInLeftBig</option>
          <option value="fadeInRight">fadeInRight</option>
          <option value="fadeInRightBig">fadeInRightBig</option>
          <option value="fadeInUp">fadeInUp</option>
          <option value="fadeInUpBig">fadeInUpBig</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Flippers">
          <option value="flipInX">flipInX</option>
          <option value="flipInY">flipInY</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Lightspeed">
          <option value="lightSpeedIn">lightSpeedIn</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Rotating Entrances">
          <option value="rotateIn">rotateIn</option>
          <option value="rotateInDownLeft">rotateInDownLeft</option>
          <option value="rotateInDownRight">rotateInDownRight</option>
          <option value="rotateInUpLeft">rotateInUpLeft</option>
          <option value="rotateInUpRight">rotateInUpRight</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Sliding Entrances">
          <option value="slideInUp">slideInUp</option>
          <option value="slideInDown">slideInDown</option>
          <option value="slideInLeft">slideInLeft</option>
          <option value="slideInRight">slideInRight</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Zoom Entrances">
          <option value="zoomIn">zoomIn</option>
          <option value="zoomInDown">zoomInDown</option>
          <option value="zoomInLeft">zoomInLeft</option>
          <option value="zoomInRight">zoomInRight</option>
          <option value="zoomInUp">zoomInUp</option>
        </optgroup>
        
        <optgroup label="Specials">
          <option value="rollIn">rollIn</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exits</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exit">
        <optgroup label="Attention Seekers">
          <option value="bounce">bounce</option>
          <option value="flash">flash</option>
          <option value="pulse">pulse</option>
          <option value="rubberBand">rubberBand</option>
          <option value="shake">shake</option>
          <option value="swing">swing</option>
          <option value="tada">tada</option>
          <option value="wobble">wobble</option>
          <option value="jello">jello</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Bouncing Exits">
          <option value="bounceOut">bounceOut</option>
          <option value="bounceOutDown">bounceOutDown</option>
          <option value="bounceOutLeft">bounceOutLeft</option>
          <option value="bounceOutRight">bounceOutRight</option>
          <option value="bounceOutUp">bounceOutUp</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Fading Exits">
          <option value="fadeOut">fadeOut</option>
          <option value="fadeOutDown">fadeOutDown</option>
          <option value="fadeOutDownBig">fadeOutDownBig</option>
          <option value="fadeOutLeft">fadeOutLeft</option>
          <option value="fadeOutLeftBig">fadeOutLeftBig</option>
          <option value="fadeOutRight">fadeOutRight</option>
          <option value="fadeOutRightBig">fadeOutRightBig</option>
          <option value="fadeOutUp">fadeOutUp</option>
          <option value="fadeOutUpBig">fadeOutUpBig</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Flippers">
          <option value="flipOutX" selected>flipOutX</option>
          <option value="flipOutY">flipOutY</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Lightspeed">
          <option value="lightSpeedOut">lightSpeedOut</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Rotating Exits">
          <option value="rotateOut">rotateOut</option>
          <option value="rotateOutDownLeft">rotateOutDownLeft</option>
          <option value="rotateOutDownRight">rotateOutDownRight</option>
          <option value="rotateOutUpLeft">rotateOutUpLeft</option>
          <option value="rotateOutUpRight">rotateOutUpRight</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Sliding Exits">
          <option value="slideOutUp">slideOutUp</option>
          <option value="slideOutDown">slideOutDown</option>
          <option value="slideOutLeft">slideOutLeft</option>
          <option value="slideOutRight">slideOutRight</option>
        </optgroup>        
        <optgroup label="Zoom Exits">
          <option value="zoomOut">zoomOut</option>
          <option value="zoomOutDown">zoomOutDown</option>
          <option value="zoomOutLeft">zoomOutLeft</option>
          <option value="zoomOutRight">zoomOutRight</option>
          <option value="zoomOutUp">zoomOutUp</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Specials">
          <option value="rollOut">rollOut</option>
        </optgroup>
        
      </select>
   </div>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
</form>
    
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```